# Python shell in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-idle

Is there a way to have a python IDLE shell, like how it is seen on windows? Sorry if this topic has been raised before, I did not find it.

*Using Linux mint 17.1 rebecca, Cinnamon 32 bit*

Comment: Why just don't write the command python in the terminal?

Comment: Because it decided to think pyhton is not there. _But it is, oddly._

Comment: In such case, idle (dependent on python being there) won't be of much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try installing it from terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install idle-python3.2
```

If you want to use python 3.4 then just do:

```
sudo apt-get install idle-python3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the "idle" package.  Many distros break the core python installation into several pieces, and idle is usually one that is packaged separately.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want IDLE, just run `python -m idlelib.idle`

Comment: thanks. Ima noob at linux, so i just wanted to check.